# How to get Facebook like button to add a website and add the user to our Facebook page

Tags: html, facebook, social-networking

I've just set up a new website at http://www.elitefightkit.co.nz and we also have a Facebook page which I don't have the url to hand at the moment (but it's called Elite Fight Kit). I want to add Facebook like buttons to my website. I can understand how to add them for product pages but I want to have a 'join us on facebook' button at the base of the page in a footer I'm producing so visitors can be added to the list of people on our Facebook page. We're growing a nice group of people over there.

I've looked into the Facebook like button and it seems to suggest that when user clicks it (if configured correctly) a feed item will be added to the users profile to say they like my website and provide a link back to the site. It seems I either have them like the website or like the Facebook group. That's great BUT I wondered if there was a way to have them click the like button, add the link to the website but ALSO join them to our Facebook page. Is there a way or will that be two seperate buttons?

This article was helpful when looking into the Facebook like button: http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/04/adding-facebook-like-buttons-to-your-site-is-damn-easy/ it pretty much got me rolling, although the Facebook developer page wasn't too hard to get my head around either. :)

Hope someone has some experience with this that can throw some light on it for me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into a similar request before but decided - given the current social plugin documentation - that it could only be done with two separate buttons. My advice would be to make the Like button on your website point to your Facebook page, with a prominent link back to your website from there. Without wanting to state the obvious, any wall posts that then appear for people liking your page will effectively advertise both!

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to drive traffic to the main website rather than bounce them off of the Facebook page but it's nice to have them join the page to keep up to date on daily deals. I think 2 buttons is the way to go.